# Copy/paste games from Chess StackExchange to lichess.org

Tags: bug

When I encounter an interesting question on Chess StackExchange, I would like to import that game to http://lichess.org, to be able to analyze it with Stockfish. When I use the "Copy game" option (for example from [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/33345/23857)) and paste that PGN into https://lichess.org/paste, it does not work (I get an empty board).

It seems that the problem is the `[FEN ""]` tag: if I remove it, it works. If I replace that tag with `[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]`, it also works.

Is this a bug in lichess or in stackexchange? In other words, is the empty string a valid FEN position?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a bug in lichess or in stackexchange?

That's an easy one. The answer is "No".

The StackExchange replayer works with [FEN ""] as per StackExchange spec, so that is certainly not a bug. As for whether it is a bug in Lichess, I doubt it very much. Surprisingly as it may seem there is no requirement for your requirements for how these things should work in your opinion to be reflected in the way the different organizations implement their own requirements.

Comment: I would expect that those requirements are based on some standards. I asked whether the [FEN ""] tag is a valid FEN position, according to the FEN standard. I have looked in the https://ia802908.us.archive.org/26/items/pgn-standard-1994-03-12/PGN_standard_1994-03-12.txt page and I don't find any mention that says that an empty FEN string would represent the starting position. I also looked in https://www.chessprogramming.org/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation. Do you have access to the StackExchange replayer specifications? Did you find there any mention about an empty FEN string?